# Wmic /format switch invalid XSL?

Tags: xslt, output, wmic

I have a quick question, should be relatively simple for those who have some more experience in WMI-command processor than I do (and since I'm an absolute beginner thats not hard :-) )

I fail to understand why wmic /format switch works the way it does. I open up cmd.exe and type

```
wmic process list brief /format:htable > processlist.html
```

this does exactly what I want and no bothers further on. Whereas if I go to wmic processor, and try to execute the same command exactly as above...

```
wmic:root\cli>process list brief /format:htable > processlist.html
```

I receive the error tag: "Invalid XSL format (or) file name."

[image: http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/5383/37tn.png]

Here goes the screenshot. Note I have already copied XSL files from wbem to sys32 dir

Can someone explain to me why these 2 commands that for me look exactly the same, with the only difference that one is executed outside wmic environment and the other one is from inside, the latter one doesn't work? I just fail to understand it.

Please advise so I can comprehend this a bit better! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use CMD.EXE `>` redirection while you are within the interactive WMIC context. That can't work.

You can use the WMIC `/output:filename` switch while in interactive mode. Each subsequent command will overwrite the output of the previous command. You can get multiple commands to go to the same file by using `/append:filename` instead. You can reset the output back to stdout using `/output:stdout`.

```
/output:processlist.html
process list brief /format:htable
/output:stdout
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Thanks dbenham :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
copy /y %WINDIR%\system32\wbem\en-US\*.xsl %WINDIR%\system32\
```

And then

```
wmic:root\cli>process list brief /format:htable.xsl > processlist.html
```

Note the presence of the extension after "htable"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying a full path in the wmic:root\cli>process call?  My bets are that the first worked because it output the file to the current directory.

Comment: Just tested (on a different W7 machine) - issue is the same. Thanks for response!

Comment: see this link... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757287(v=ws.10).aspx   They suggest this syntax:  /FORMAT:"htable.xsl":"datatype=<datatype>":"sortby=<property>". For example, PROCESS GET /FORMAT:"htable.xsl":"datatype=number":"sortby=ProcessId".

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out soon. If it works thats fine. It still surprises me though that it requires much more gymnastics to execute from inside since the default format is perfectly fine for me :-)